# In the Pokemon Card Game what is a group of Pokemon called?

Tags: pokemon

There is...

- **herd** of cattle
- **pride** of lions
- **murder** of crows
- **school** of fish
- **colony** of ants

... and a **[something]** of Pokemon?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about board games, and probably should be on the SciFi and Fantasy SE site.

Comment: It's *kind of* board/card game related, though I see where it doesn't necessarily fall in this case. I took my best shot at the right site - I'll try over there. :)

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey If you are trying elsewhere English Language and Usage would also be somewhere to look

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I can see how that might fall into B&CG.SE with the card game, I just think from a scope perspective you'd be better off on one of the other two mentioned sites.

Comment: @SocioMatt While this question might fit better on one of the other sites that doesn't necessarily mean it is off topic here. It is a question related to a card game which is the main criteria for on-topicness.

Comment: @diego That creates a line I'm not sure about. If that were true, wouldn't a question like "What are a group of urak hai called?" be considered on-topic because there is a _Lord of the Rings_ game? Should that be on B&CG.SE? Or down another level, should we be asking whether gravitational pulls of wormholes suck in ships, since that is the premise of the game _Gravwell_?

Comment: @SocioMatt I agree, and that is probably something that should be discussed on Meta. However as it currently stands the definition for on-topic only states that it 'must relate to a game that is on topic', and doesn't have any limiters on how related something must be.

Comment: @diego I've added a [Meta question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/should-game-adjacent-questions-be-on-topic) dealing with this topic.

Comment: Whether or not this is on topic, it's certainly not a game recommendation question!

Comment: Question  belongs to English Language SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Sci-fi and Fantasy Stackexchange

Comment: There isn't one true site for all questions.  There is considerable overlap in the StackExchange network.

Comment: @Pureferret wouldn't it be more suitable on an English Language SE?

Sure Pokemon aren't real, but it is a question about the English language, not about pokemon or anything sci-fi/fantasy related.

Comment: @Othya ELU sometimes frowns on [unusual cases](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/65938/15661).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not actually about the Pokemon card game.

Comment: The updated question that includes 'In the Pokemon Card Game' doesn't really make sense since Pokemon in the card game doesn't really come in groups like they do in the anime or video games. (Unless you want something like 'playset' or 'deck' :)  )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A group of Pokemon is called the same as group of animals.

So for a cattle-like Pokemon it's "herd", for lion-like Pokemon it's "pride", and so on.